# Matrix $I_i(x)$

Tags: linear-algebra, notation

I'm wondering what means this matrix $I_i(x)$ , I find it in the context of the next exercise:

Let be $b\in\mathbb{R}^n$ and $A=[a_1 ... a_n]\in \mathbb{R}^n$. Define
\begin{equation}
A_i(b) = (a_1 ... b ...a_n)
\end{equation}
like the matrix A with $i-$esim column replaced for the vector $b$. Proof that $A~I_i(x)=A_i(b)$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R}^n$.

Answer (score 0):

$I$ is the identity matrix. $$ I_{3 \times 3} = \begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 1 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}. $$ It is common in linear algebra to refer to identity matrices with this notation.

From the context you provided, $I_{i}(x)$ must mean $I$ with the $i$-th column replaced by vector $x$. It seems that the claim is either incorrect or there is not enough information about $b$ or $x$.